# Can't insert this JSON data to SQL Server?

Tags: python, json, sql-server

I'm trying to insert the following JSON data into a table on our SQL Server with python code.

```
('{"ITEMCODE":"A00975605","DISPLAYREVISIONNO":1,"ITEMNAME":"ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","ITEMNAME_ID":"~0000PCLAZ","ITEMTYPE":2,"ITEMTYPEEX":0,"PRODUCTTYPE":12,"LOTTYPE":"S1","EDITIONNOTYPE":0,"ISINVENTORY":2,"HOSTMANAGETYPE":-1,"SHIPMENTJUDGETYPE":null,"UNITVOLUME":1000,"TAREWEIGHT":0,"DEFAULTRECIPECODE":null,"ISQUALITYCHECK":1,"ISALLOCATEMORELOT":0,"ISINSERTLOTCHECK":-1,"RECEIPTVOLUMELIMIT":"10","RECEIPTZONECODE":"FS01","WAREHOUSEZONECODE":null,"SHIPMENTZONECODE":null,"LABELCODE":null,"THEME":null,"ARTICLENO":null,"ARTICLENAME":null,"ARTICLENAME_ID":null,"PACKAGEINDICATOR":null,"PRODUCTIONFLOWNO":null,"RECEIPTFLOWNO":null,"TESTFLOWNO":null,"RECORDREVIEWFLOWNO":null,"SHIPMENTGMPFLOWNO":null,"SHIPMENTGQPFLOWNO":null,"NOTE":null,"NOTE_ID":null,"STRENGTHUNITFLAG":0,"MEDICINEDIVISION":null,"EVALUATIONCLASS":"6200","SAMPLINGVALUEFORLIST":null,"STOCKVALUEFORLIST":null,"FILLINGVOLUME":null,"FILLINGVOLUMEMAXIMUMLIMIT":null,"FILLINGVOLUMEMINIMUMLIMIT":null,"FILTRATIONTYPE":null,"STERILIZATIONTYPE":null,"BOTTLEWASHING":null,"STRENGTHUNITFLAGEX":0,"DEFAULTMAKERCODE":"H75776","PRODUCTCODEFORBCD ":null,"STOCKCONDITIONCODE":5,"METALUSE":null,"AUTOALLOCFLAG":1,"INNERPACKAGEVOLUME ":1000,"AREACODE":"A1","STANDARDSTRENGTHUNITRATIO":1}',)
('{"ITEMCODE":"A00975612","DISPLAYREVISIONNO":1,"ITEMNAME":"BCDEFGHIJKLMNO","ITEMNAME_ID":"~0000PCLHS","ITEMTYPE":2,"ITEMTYPEEX":0,"PRODUCTTYPE":12,"LOTTYPE":"S1","EDITIONNOTYPE":0,"ISINVENTORY":2,"HOSTMANAGETYPE":-1,"SHIPMENTJUDGETYPE":null,"UNITVOLUME":1000,"TAREWEIGHT":0,"DEFAULTRECIPECODE":null,"ISQUALITYCHECK":1,"ISALLOCATEMORELOT":0,"ISINSERTLOTCHECK":-1,"RECEIPTVOLUMELIMIT":"10","RECEIPTZONECODE":"FS01","WAREHOUSEZONECODE":null,"SHIPMENTZONECODE":null,"LABELCODE":null,"THEME":null,"ARTICLENO":null,"ARTICLENAME":null,"ARTICLENAME_ID":null,"PACKAGEINDICATOR":null,"PRODUCTIONFLOWNO":null,"RECEIPTFLOWNO":null,"TESTFLOWNO":null,"RECORDREVIEWFLOWNO":null,"SHIPMENTGMPFLOWNO":null,"SHIPMENTGQPFLOWNO":null,"NOTE":null,"NOTE_ID":null,"STRENGTHUNITFLAG":0,"MEDICINEDIVISION":null,"EVALUATIONCLASS":"6200","SAMPLINGVALUEFORLIST":null,"STOCKVALUEFORLIST":null,"FILLINGVOLUME":null,"FILLINGVOLUMEMAXIMUMLIMIT":null,"FILLINGVOLUMEMINIMUMLIMIT":null,"FILTRATIONTYPE":null,"STERILIZATIONTYPE":null,"BOTTLEWASHING":null,"STRENGTHUNITFLAGEX":0,"DEFAULTMAKERCODE":"H75776","PRODUCTCODEFORBCD ":null,"STOCKCONDITIONCODE":5,"METALUSE":null,"AUTOALLOCFLAG":1,"INNERPACKAGEVOLUME ":1000,"AREACODE":"A1","STANDARDSTRENGTHUNITRATIO":1}',)
('{"ITEMCODE":"A00977746","DISPLAYREVISIONNO":1,"ITEMNAME":"CDEFGHIJKLMNOP","ITEMNAME_ID":"~0000PCJZN","ITEMTYPE":2,"ITEMTYPEEX":0,"PRODUCTTYPE":12,"LOTTYPE":"S1","EDITIONNOTYPE":0,"ISINVENTORY":2,"HOSTMANAGETYPE":-1,"SHIPMENTJUDGETYPE":null,"UNITVOLUME":1000,"TAREWEIGHT":0,"DEFAULTRECIPECODE":null,"ISQUALITYCHECK":1,"ISALLOCATEMORELOT":0,"ISINSERTLOTCHECK":-1,"RECEIPTVOLUMELIMIT":"10","RECEIPTZONECODE":"FS01","WAREHOUSEZONECODE":null,"SHIPMENTZONECODE":null,"LABELCODE":null,"THEME":null,"ARTICLENO":null,"ARTICLENAME":null,"ARTICLENAME_ID":null,"PACKAGEINDICATOR":null,"PRODUCTIONFLOWNO":null,"RECEIPTFLOWNO":null,"TESTFLOWNO":null,"RECORDREVIEWFLOWNO":null,"SHIPMENTGMPFLOWNO":null,"SHIPMENTGQPFLOWNO":null,"NOTE":null,"NOTE_ID":null,"STRENGTHUNITFLAG":0,"MEDICINEDIVISION":null,"EVALUATIONCLASS":"6200","SAMPLINGVALUEFORLIST":null,"STOCKVALUEFORLIST":null,"FILLINGVOLUME":null,"FILLINGVOLUMEMAXIMUMLIMIT":null,"FILLINGVOLUMEMINIMUMLIMIT":null,"FILTRATIONTYPE":null,"STERILIZATIONTYPE":null,"BOTTLEWASHING":null,"STRENGTHUNITFLAGEX":0,"DEFAULTMAKERCODE":"H75776","PRODUCTCODEFORBCD ":null,"STOCKCONDITIONCODE":5,"METALUSE":null,"AUTOALLOCFLAG":1,"INNERPACKAGEVOLUME ":1000,"AREACODE":"A1","STANDARDSTRENGTHUNITRATIO":1}',)
('{"ITEMCODE":"A00977753","DISPLAYREVISIONNO":1,"ITEMNAME":"DEFGHIJKLMNOPQ","ITEMNAME_ID":"~0000PCJZP","ITEMTYPE":2,"ITEMTYPEEX":0,"PRODUCTTYPE":12,"LOTTYPE":"S1","EDITIONNOTYPE":0,"ISINVENTORY":2,"HOSTMANAGETYPE":-1,"SHIPMENTJUDGETYPE":null,"UNITVOLUME":1000,"TAREWEIGHT":0,"DEFAULTRECIPECODE":null,"ISQUALITYCHECK":1,"ISALLOCATEMORELOT":0,"ISINSERTLOTCHECK":-1,"RECEIPTVOLUMELIMIT":"10","RECEIPTZONECODE":"FS01","WAREHOUSEZONECODE":null,"SHIPMENTZONECODE":null,"LABELCODE":null,"THEME":null,"ARTICLENO":null,"ARTICLENAME":null,"ARTICLENAME_ID":null,"PACKAGEINDICATOR":null,"PRODUCTIONFLOWNO":null,"RECEIPTFLOWNO":null,"TESTFLOWNO":null,"RECORDREVIEWFLOWNO":null,"SHIPMENTGMPFLOWNO":null,"SHIPMENTGQPFLOWNO":null,"NOTE":null,"NOTE_ID":null,"STRENGTHUNITFLAG":0,"MEDICINEDIVISION":null,"EVALUATIONCLASS":"6200","SAMPLINGVALUEFORLIST":null,"STOCKVALUEFORLIST":null,"FILLINGVOLUME":null,"FILLINGVOLUMEMAXIMUMLIMIT":null,"FILLINGVOLUMEMINIMUMLIMIT":null,"FILTRATIONTYPE":null,"STERILIZATIONTYPE":null,"BOTTLEWASHING":null,"STRENGTHUNITFLAGEX":0,"DEFAULTMAKERCODE":"H75776","PRODUCTCODEFORBCD ":null,"STOCKCONDITIONCODE":5,"METALUSE":null,"AUTOALLOCFLAG":1,"INNERPACKAGEVOLUME ":1000,"AREACODE":"A1","STANDARDSTRENGTHUNITRATIO":1}',)
('{"ITEMCODE":"A00977760","DISPLAYREVISIONNO":1,"ITEMNAME":"EFGHIJKLMNOPQR","ITEMNAME_ID":"~0000PCJZR","ITEMTYPE":2,"ITEMTYPEEX":0,"PRODUCTTYPE":12,"LOTTYPE":"S1","EDITIONNOTYPE":0,"ISINVENTORY":2,"HOSTMANAGETYPE":-1,"SHIPMENTJUDGETYPE":null,"UNITVOLUME":1000,"TAREWEIGHT":0,"DEFAULTRECIPECODE":null,"ISQUALITYCHECK":1,"ISALLOCATEMORELOT":0,"ISINSERTLOTCHECK":-1,"RECEIPTVOLUMELIMIT":"10","RECEIPTZONECODE":"FS01","WAREHOUSEZONECODE":null,"SHIPMENTZONECODE":null,"LABELCODE":null,"THEME":null,"ARTICLENO":null,"ARTICLENAME":null,"ARTICLENAME_ID":null,"PACKAGEINDICATOR":null,"PRODUCTIONFLOWNO":null,"RECEIPTFLOWNO":null,"TESTFLOWNO":null,"RECORDREVIEWFLOWNO":null,"SHIPMENTGMPFLOWNO":null,"SHIPMENTGQPFLOWNO":null,"NOTE":null,"NOTE_ID":null,"STRENGTHUNITFLAG":0,"MEDICINEDIVISION":null,"EVALUATIONCLASS":"6200","SAMPLINGVALUEFORLIST":null,"STOCKVALUEFORLIST":null,"FILLINGVOLUME":null,"FILLINGVOLUMEMAXIMUMLIMIT":null,"FILLINGVOLUMEMINIMUMLIMIT":null,"FILTRATIONTYPE":null,"STERILIZATIONTYPE":null,"BOTTLEWASHING":null,"STRENGTHUNITFLAGEX":0,"DEFAULTMAKERCODE":"H75776","PRODUCTCODEFORBCD ":null,"STOCKCONDITIONCODE":5,"METALUSE":null,"AUTOALLOCFLAG":1,"INNERPACKAGEVOLUME ":1000,"AREACODE":"A1","STANDARDSTRENGTHUNITRATIO":1}',)
```

And if I could solve this with executing a SQL statement, I would be so happy.
Because our Application server with python and SQL Server are completely different machines. They are actually far apart each other.

Attempting the code below, I have run into an error. Could anyone give me some advice?

```
def jsonINSERT(_cn, _cur, jdata):
    SQL = """
    INSERT INTO TSTTBL VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    """
    _cur.executemany(SQL, jdata)
    _cn.commit()
    return
```

> 'The SQL contains 56 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'

## **I did like this eventually.**

```
def jsonINSERT(_cn, _cur, sql, jdata):
    _cur.executemany(sql, jdata)
    _cn.commit()
    return


#From Oracle
fetch_dat = cur.fetchall()

#To take tuple off
fetch_dat = [json.loads(t[0]) for t in fetch_dat]

#To declare columns for the query
columns = tuple(fetch_dat[0].keys())
params = ['?'  for _ in range(len(columns))]
    
#To declare value for the query
data = [tuple(e.values()) for e in fetch_dat]


#Composing the sql!
sql = 'INSERT INTO TSTTBL ({}) VALUES ({})'.format(','.join(columns), ','.join(params))
    
jsonINSERT(mscn, mscur, sql, data)
```

Comment: Isn’t the error message rather informative? Speaking of, is that the entire error message?

Comment: Thank AMC, I has just pasted the JSON data on again. As nobody could see the image of JSON data I pasted before, I thought.  Can you see that JSON data?    The message was all I had from python.  My current code seemed not to recognize the record level.

Comment: I appreciate Dale K correcting my horrible English.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to go about this, but I think an example will help, you may need something like this:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES (%s)", json_vals)
```

OR essentially,

```
db.execute(yourQueryHere, json_vals)
```

Comment: After changing the method 'executemany' ===> 'execute', I got an other error. Like This, 'The SQL contains 56 parameter markers, but 9956 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'     In short, The JSON data includes 9956 records. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't understand having to declare columns for the query. Thank everyone.